# How to pass an array of IDs from one Laravel query to another

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 queries from two different tables. First one contains the IDs which I would like to use in the second query. For now I do it like this. I extract the IDs into a new array, and then use this array in `->whereIn()` in second query.

```
$campaign = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('mc_spots')
            ->select('s_customer', 's_product', 'spotid')
            ->where('s_starttermin', '>=', date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateFrom)))
            ->where('s_lastrun', '<=', date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateUntil)))
            ->where('s_media', '=', $media)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($products) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++) {
                    $query->orwhere('s_product', '=', $products[$i]);
                }
            })

            ->get();

$campaignID = [];

        foreach ($campaign as $c) {
            array_push($campaignID, $c->spotid);
        }

$table = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('schaltdaten_tv_de')
                ->select('*')
                ->join('epgdata_channel', 'schaltdaten_tv_de.cid', '=', 'epgdata_channel.channelid')
                ->join('mc_spots', 'schaltdaten_tv_de.ReferenceDescription', '=', 'mc_spots.spotid')
                ->whereIn('ReferenceDescription', $campaignID)
                ->groupBy('epgdata_2013.id')
                ->orderBy('StartofBreak', 'ASC')
                ->limit(500)
                ->get();
```

Is there more convenient way to do this without looping through every item of `$campaign`?

Comment: The code in your question is only using Laravel's fluent query builder and not Eloquent.

Comment: Ok. I've edited my question. Thx

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I use Laravel 5.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pluck `id` from first query which gives you array of ids and you can use it in second query.

```
$campaign = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('mc_spots')
        ->select('s_customer', 's_product', 'spotid')
        ->where('s_starttermin', '>=', date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateFrom)))
        ->where('s_lastrun', '<=', date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateUntil)))
        ->where('s_media', '=', $media)
        ->where(function ($query) use ($products) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++) {
                $query->orwhere('s_product', '=', $products[$i]);
            }
        })

        ->pluck('spotid');
```

Now, use `spot id` array in `whereIn` of second as ,

```
$table = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('schaltdaten_tv_de')
            ->select('*')
            ->join('epgdata_channel', 'schaltdaten_tv_de.cid', '=', 'epgdata_channel.channelid')
            ->join('mc_spots', 'schaltdaten_tv_de.ReferenceDescription', '=', 'mc_spots.spotid')
            ->whereIn('ReferenceDescription', $campaign)
            ->groupBy('epgdata_2013.id')
            ->orderBy('StartofBreak', 'ASC')
            ->limit(500)
            ->get();
```

Hope you understand

Comment: Cool. Is it possible to pluck a SUM column from second query? I need to get `SUM('price')` in `$table` from all items. Right now I do it like in this example - assign `$sum = 0`, and then loop through all items and make `$sum += $table->price`... which is pretty bad solution though...

Comment: You mean `$sum = $table->sum()` ? But how can I pass the `price` (name of the column)?

Comment: It's simple, you have to replace `->get()` to `->sum('price')`. You will get sum of price column

Comment: I do but I get wrong results. Instead of 16.000.000 I get 25... :/

Comment: Is your price field is of integer type or string ? sometime string type gives problems

Comment: What do you want actually ? sum of price column for result of second query or sum of price column for every record ?

Comment: Sum of prices for every record in that query.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
$campaignID = $campaign->pluck('spotid');
```

Pluck doc:

> The pluck method retrieves all of the values for a given key

And as Sagar said, it retrieves an array which is the second argument to our `->whereIn()`

Comment: `pluck()` already gives array so you can't convert it to array again

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by use of array_column()

Like this

```
$campaignID=array_column($campaign,'spotid')
```

Make sure that `$campaign` must be an array. if it is object the convert it into array like this `json_decode(json_encode($campaign),true)`

For exapmle

```
$t='[{"id":49},{"id":61},{"id":5},{"id":58}]' ;
array_column(json_decode($t,true),'id')
```

It will give output as

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you're already joining the `mc_spots` table in the 2nd query you could always just add the same constraints from the 1st query:

```
$table = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('schaltdaten_tv_de')
    ->select('*')
    ->join('epgdata_channel', 'schaltdaten_tv_de.cid', '=', 'epgdata_channel.channelid')
    ->join('mc_spots', 'schaltdaten_tv_de.ReferenceDescription', '=', 'mc_spots.spotid')
    ->where('mc_spots.s_starttermin', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($dateFrom))
    ->where('mc_spots.s_lastrun', '<=', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($dateUntil))
    ->where('mc_spots.s_media', $media)
    ->whereIn('s_product', $products)
    ->groupBy('epgdata_2013.id')
    ->orderBy('StartofBreak', 'ASC')
    ->limit(500)
    ->get();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am trying to implement your solution but the page is just loading now. When I go to MySQL processes, I can see that it just keeps sending the data. I had to kill process manually.

Comment: @harunB10 I've added a different solution for you.